# How to remove a user entry from dconf?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, dconf

By mistake, I added an entry called `com.canonical.unity.devices.blacklist` to *dconf* when trying to lock the value for the `blacklist` key under *com->canonical->unity->devices*. How can I remove it?

[image: Entry added by mistake.]

---

## Here is what I did before this happened:

Created a file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/00_devices-blacklist.gschema.override` with

> [com.canonical.unity.devices]
>   blacklist=['01D3FDBD88BEAC80-OS', '8045-6F4E-PEN']

- Recompiled the schemas with 
  `sudo glib-compile-schemas --strict /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`.
- Created a file `/etc/dconf/profile/user` with

  > user-db:user
  >   system-db:local
  >   system-db:ibus
- Created a file `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-devices-blacklist` with

  > [com.canonical.unity.devices]
  >   blacklist=['01D3FDBD88BEAC80-OS', '8045-6F4E-PEN']
- Created a file `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/devices-blacklist` with

  > # prevent changes to the list of devices not shown in the launcher
  >   /com/canonical/unity/devices/blacklist
- Created a file `/etc/profile.d/dconf-profile.sh` with

  > export DCONF_PROFILE=local
- Ran `sudo dconf update` and rebooted.
- My ubuntu gave me some errors regarding `/etc/profile` so I deleted the `/etc/profile.d/dconf-profile.sh`, rebooted and it booted without errors, but that entry was added and the devices were still reappearing in the launcher every time I booted.
- Then, I removed `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/00_devices-blacklist.gschema.override` and edited `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml`, changing the default key value to what I wanted. After recompiling the schemas, the devices were no longer showing up on boot.

But that entry is still there. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions in [help.gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en) are not very clear. Apparently, *keyfiles* like `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-devices-blacklist`, which has

> [com.canonical.unity.devices]
>   blacklist=['01D3FDBD88BEAC80-OS', '8045-6F4E-PEN']

create *new* entries in *dconf*, hence the entry `com.canonical.unity.devices`.

I removed the file, rebooted and everything was solved.